# Loop through all images in table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, html-table

I'm not that good in jQuery, or not good at all, but I need to make a jQuery/Javascript function which will 
search for all images in a particular table. So the criterias are that the table must have an attribute 'summary'
and it must be equal to 'forum' (summary=forum)

```
<table width="100%" class="ms-disc"  dir="none" border="0"
 cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="1" summary="Forum">
```

So if this is the table then I need to check if td has class "particular class"
`<td class="ms-disc-bordered">`. It is possible that in that td can be another table and only in that table there is a td ... 
But this is not important, just to know it is nested and can be on lower lvl's that image.

Then the image inside can be resized.

Now I have this code:

```
function ResizeImages()
{
    jQuery(document).ready(function () 
    {
        var table = $("").find()
        table.each("td")(function()
        {
            if(hassummary & summary.equals("forum"))
            {
                var img=table.find("image")
                img.height="";
                img.weight="";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
so this is hierarchy:

```
<table summary="forum">
 .....
    <table>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="particular class">
                    <a link>
                        <image> the one i need to get</image>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> </table></table> ....
```

Comment: First: Is there really no way to mark the image somehow? Second: do I state correctly that the `img` is always (nested) inside a `td.particularClass` which is (nested) inside a `table` with an attribute `summary=forum`?

Comment: if a nested table should only be looked at if it's inside a marked `<td>` then that's quite important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery code to search your images is:

```
$('table[summary="forum"] td.particular.class img').attr({
    height: '',
    width: ''
});
```

Despite the utility of this code, I think the most important part for you is to understand the jQuery selector. The selector is composed of this sub-selectors:

- **table[summary="forum"]** search all `<table>` elements with an attribute named `summary` equals to `"forum"`.
- **td.particular.class** search all `<td>` elements having both the classes `particular` and `class`
- **img** search all `<img>` elements.

The sub-selectors are separated by spaces. This means that `<img>` elements must be placed inside `<td>` elements and these must be placed inside `<table>` elements. Other details are in the full documentations for [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Once you find the correct `<img>` elements, you can set their attributes using the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.

Comment: do i need to put it in for each or it will execute on every image anyway?

Comment: It works for every item in the set of matched elements (i.e. for every image in the table).

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
$('table[summary=forum] td.particular.class img').each(function(){
   $(this).width(w).height(h);
});
```

Comment: hmm nope it doesn't do it, but does it get the right table? And the td might not be in the same table but in the next table that is nested in the table with (summary=forum)

Comment: with the update markup, the new selector above should now does it